# How to make Google Diff Match Patch prefer changes at the end of a string?

Tags: javascript, google-diff-match-patch

I am using the `diff_main` method of Google's DiffMatchPatch library to get diffs which I then use in my app. Consider this case:

Old string:

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
   for (var id in this._dependentsById)
     this._dependentsById[id]._compute();
};
```

New string:

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  for (var id in this._dependentsById)
    this._dependentsById[id]._compute();
};

Tracker.autorun = function (f) {
  constructingComputation = true;
  var c = new Tracker.Computation(f);
  return c;
};
```

The addition diff I get is:

```
;
};

Tracker.autorun = function (f) {
  constructingComputation = true;
  var c = new Tracker.Computation(f);
  return c
```

Whereas it would seem that for human consumption a more reasonable diff would be:

```
Tracker.autorun = function (f) {
  constructingComputation = true;
  var c = new Tracker.Computation(f);
  return c;
};
```

Is there any way I can make DiffMatchPatch produce the second result rather than the first?

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/puje78vL/1/

Comment: want to share a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry everyone for not updating this sooner with further details. I was very ill and didn't get to my laptop until now.

Answer (score 8):

I have created a [<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/tikoflano/2ss0css5/1/) based on the library's author [example page](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html) (assuming that you want the Javascript version based on the question tag).

And using this code would give me what you expect:

```
var dmp = new diff_match_patch();

function launch() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
  var text2 = document.getElementById('text2').value;

  var d = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2);
  var ds = dmp.diff_prettyHtml(d);

  document.getElementById('outputdiv').innerHTML = ds;
}
```

You can also look at the console and see the raw answer (the arrays) where you can also see that `diff_main` is returning what you are expecting. Are you doing something different? If so please share your code.

**New Info**

Now that you provided the full text I can give you a better answer: **the result you are seeing is ok, it is just the way the algorithm works**

I'll try to explain to you what is going on and how to fix this. Let's take a look at the final part of each text:

**Text 1**

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  for (var id in this._dependentsById)
    this._dependentsById[id]._compute();
};
```

**Text 2**

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  for (var id in this._dependentsById)
    this._dependentsById[id]._compute();
};

Tracker.autorun = function (f) {
  constructingComputation = true;
  var c = new Tracker.Computation(f);
  return c;
};
```

Lets notice this:

1. The final **};** of the `changed` function on *Text 1* has no carriage return after it.
2. The final **};** of the `changed` function on *Text 2* has carriage return after it.
3. The final **};** of the `autorun` function on *Text 2* has no carriage return after it.

So the algorithm that calculates the diffs will match `1` with `3`, leaving `2` as the added text. This is why tou are getting that output.

Now in order to get the desired output you will need to match `1` with `2`. This means add a new empty line at the end of *Text 1* as you can see on tour updated <kbd>[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tikoflano/puje78vL/2/)</kbd>:

```
Tracker.Dependency.prototype.changed = function () {
  for (var id in this._dependentsById)
    this._dependentsById[id]._compute();
};[PRESS ENTER HERE TO ADD NEW LINE]
```

Take notice that if you use just this text the algorithm will work correctly (as I showd in my orginal answer). It is after you add some more text when this confussion starts to happen, not sure why.

Comment: Yeah when I made a fiddle with such an isolated test case, it worked fine. I have to look into the code a bit more, but I have been quite ill last few days :(

Comment: Then you will need to provide your code, environment, etc. Otherwise there is no way we can help any more.

Comment: I added a fiddle that demonstrates the example.

Comment: Thanks for the research. It's a little unsatisfactory to tell my users to "add new lines to the previous revision of your code". Sounds about as good as saying "it's not a bug, it's a feature".

Comment: What if you add the line to the first text programatically? The end user won't notice.

Comment: Well if you add a line also to text 2, than the problem shows up again.

Comment: Maybe try another diff library. Like prettydiff.